# getting resultset pollenrich with camel jpa consumer

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to obtain JPA entity using pollEnrich

```
.pollEnrich("jpa://com.entity.AbonentPay?consumeDelete=false&initialDelay=1&delay=60&timeUnit=SECONDS&maximumResults=5000&persistenceUnit=LocalDB&consumer.namedQuery=GetAccounts&consumer.resultClass=com.entity.AbonentPay&maxMessagesPerPoll=100")
```

But after that I got only one row, despite table contains hundreds of rows. How I can get all rows? I want pollEnrich behavior as usual, which gives me all table rows.

```
.from("jpa://com.entity.AbonentPay?....
```

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: Hello, Claus. Camel version is 2.14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported in such an old Camel release.

From Camel 2.18 onwards camel-jpa supports this.

From the release notes: http://camel.apache.org/camel-2180-release.html

- JPA now includes a JpaPollingConsumer implementation that better supports Content Enricher using pollEnrich to do a on-demand poll that returns either none, one or a list of entities as the result.